# Can I stored class based DSC resource in separate file from PSM file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, dsc

Currently, for my modules, I store actual code in a separate file from PSM1 file, then dot source it and use `Export-ModuleMember` to export Functions, this way it allows me easily debug/test individual functions.

I assume it's not possible since `Export-ModuleMember` does not give the option to export DSCResource but is it possible to have a similar setup for class based DSC Resources?

Comment: Have you exported the resources in DscResourcesToExport field? Class based resources have to be specified in this field in the module manifest - which also means it is mandatory to specify a module manifest for this module

Comment: Yes. Apparently it's "bug" which looks like nobody reported. Per powershell.org (http://powershell.org/forums/topic/two-clsss-dsc-resources-in-one-module/) and post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug filed against WMF 5.0. Please upvote.

https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/14288805-nested-modules-does-not-work-invoke-dscresource

Comment: Worthy to note that the uservoice link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have a module containing many DSC class based resources.
2. In that module you can have 1 class per file but you can't split it further (like Test method in one file Set method in another).
3. Powershell does not support partial classes.

Comment: Per this topic, it's not possible to have those in separate files http://powershell.org/forums/topic/two-clsss-dsc-resources-in-one-module/

Comment: Yes you can starting WMF 5.0 RTM. Check the sample @ https://github.com/nitinbps/DSCResources/tree/master/MultiClassesNestedModulesSameDir.

Comment: This does not work with Invoke-DSCResource though  try below `Invoke-DscResource -Name nestedA -ModuleName MultiClassesNestedModulesSameDir -Method Test -Property @{path = "c:\"}`

Comment: As I started to test it more I also realized that nested module is not properly functioning in WMF 5.0 RTM